# Try Catch not working?

Tags: php

I cannot make `try` work. I tried this:

```
try {
    echo 1/0;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
```

Which results on the error:

```
Warning: Division by zero in /var/www/vhosts/saliganando.com/webs/momemi/apis/interpret-bot.php on line 6
```

I tried modifying error_reporting() and ini_set() but I have only managed to either remove the warning or display it, but 'Caught exception...' is never shown.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code will never generate an exception. It generates a warning. You would need to capture the warning within an error handler (with [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/set_error_handler)) to process that error.

See [the docs on exceptions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) for plenty of examples on how Exceptions work and how to catch them, including one to mimic the functionality you're looking for:

```
function inverse($x) {
    if (!$x) {
        throw new Exception('Division by zero.');
    }
    else return 1/$x;
}

try {
    echo inverse(5) . "\n";
    echo inverse(0) . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Which generates:

```
0.2
Caught exception: Division by zero.
```

Comment: Do not forget you could throw your own exception in function registred with set_error_handler.